# Example of polymorphism preventing compiler optimization?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, compiler-construction, polymorphism

Cannot remember where I saw it now- but somewhere I read that dynamic polymorphism prevents the compiler from making various optimizations.

Besides inlining, could somebody please englighten me with any examples of such "missed" optimization opportunities which polymorphism prevents the compiler from making?

Comment: Certainly inlining.  And initialized "constants".  Can't think of anything else offhand.

Comment: I would say that those missed optimizations are the implications of failed inlining. I think that is the biggest loss and that seems to be the biggest motivation behind devirtualization.

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
Derived d;
d.vMethod(); // that will call Derived::vMethod statically (allowing inlining).
```

With (unless one of `Derived` or `Derived::vMethod` is declared `final` in C++11):

```
void foo(Derived& d)
{
    d.vMethod(); // this will call virtually vMethod (disallowing inlining).
}
```

Virtual call has an additional cost (as indirection through the vtable).

C++11 introduces `final` keyword which may turn the last example in static call.

Comment: An indirect call is also generally more expensive in terms of target prediction. With a static call, the target address can be computed in the processor's front-end, so a target misprediction can be corrected sooner. In addition, hardware prediction of variable targets is more complex (when not just predicting the same as for the last encounter with the instruction) so sometimes not accurate in simple processors and prediction is very difficult for "random" targets.

Answer (score 0):

At least in C++, polymorphic objects must be in the form of pointers or references. Sometimes this prevents the possibility of putting them on stack variables, or List types, you need to use List. Stack variables spare dynamic allocations etc.

A call to Poly.vmethod() is always resolved at compile time, even if vmethod() is virtual, while Poly->vmethod() consults the virtual method table. (Well, if the method is virtual it is meant to be polymorphic. Static methods are statically resolved in either case.)

Return value optimization (RVO) is another trick that does not have place when returning pointers or references. RVO is typically implemented by passing a hidden parameter: a pointer to a memory region, that is filled with the "returned" object. The size and the type of this region must be perfectly known at compile time.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on your RVO comment?

Comment: Polymorphic objects *can* live on the stack, in by-value collections, etc. as pointers and references can point at any memory. For example, `void f(Base &o) { o.vmethod() }` can be called like this: `Derived on_stack; f(on_stack);`.